# Passing Information in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

Okay, I'm new to programming so much grace would be appreciated. 
In GUI, I have created a JTextfield where a user can enter in their name. However, when the name is entered, the program does not save it. How can I pass information from the what the user enters to the program itself? I need to print it all out at the end but I can't figure out how to do that. Someone please answer! Thanks!

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by _"save"_. Do you mean you want the user to enter text, save that text, then clear it, enter more text, and save that, and clear.. and so on, then print out everything the user entered? If that's the case, you just need to store the inputs into any number of data structures out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getText()` method from `JTextField`:

```
JTextField myTextField = new JTextField(...);
....
String name = myTextField.getText();
```

Comment: That is correct, but also consider start reading a good tutorial about GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an ActionListener to the textfield
For example:

```
String name;
JTextField nameTextField = new JTextField();
...
myTextField.addActionListener(new NameListener());
...
protected class NameListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        name = nameTextField.getText();
    }
}
```

The ActionListener will save the text entered the name String variable when enter is pressed in the text field.